# Why can I set the properties of a privately set property?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a class `LoginManager` which has a private field `currentUser` and a public property `CurrentUser` to not allow myself to accidentally change the value of `CurrentUser` from outside the `LoginManager` class.

`CurrentUser` is `{ get; }` only but I can still change properties in the underlying `currentUser` which is private.

eg.

```
Console.WriteLine(loginManager.CurrentUser.ClockedIn.ToString()); // true
loginManager.CurrentUser.ClockedIn = false;
Console.WriteLine(loginManager.CurrentUser.ClockedIn.ToString()); // false
loginManager.CurrentUser.ClockedIn = true;
Console.WriteLine(loginManager.CurrentUser.ClockedIn.ToString()); // true
```

LoginManager.cs

```
public class LoginManager
    {
        private User? currentUser { get; set; }
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

        public event EventHandler CurrentUserChanged;

        public User? CurrentUser
        {
            get { return currentUser; }
        }

        //...
    }
```

User.cs

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool ClockedIn { get; set; }

    }
```

I want it so that I can't change `CurrentUser` from outside the `LoginManager` class. Could anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: As a side note, private members are usually declared as *fields* and not as *properties*. In other words, change `private User? currentUser { get; set; }` to `private User? currentUser;`. And while you are at it, learn about `readonly`.

Comment: the public get with no set only prevents callers from changing what currentUser inside LoginManager points at, not the contents of that User record. Jeremy answer below shows the correct way

Comment: You could put the `LoginManager` and `User` classes in their own assembly and make the `User` property setters internal.

Comment: @JesseGood I did have it as `private User? currentUser;` originally, but I changed it to the former while I was mucking around trying to get this to work. I do know about `readonly` fields, but I felt like it wasn't the appropriate approach in this case. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @grin0048 I was thinking about this. It might be my solution if I find nothing else that suits better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see the problem, the private `CurrentUser` instances `get` and `set` properties are exposed outside the class since those member variables are `public` in scope.

Why not make the `User` properties `private`?

```
public class User
{
    private Guid Id { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private string Username { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }
    private bool ClockedIn { get; set; }

}
```

Or if you need to `get` the properties mark `private set`:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public bool ClockedIn { get; private set; }
}
```

Or explicitly make them `readonly` so they can only be initialized in the `Constructor`:

```
public class User
{
    public readonly Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public readonly string Name { get; private set; }
    public readonly string Username { get; private set; }
    public readonly string Password { get; private set; }
    public readonly bool ClockedIn { get; private set; }

    public User(Guid Id, string Name, string Username, string Password, bool ClockedIn) 
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Name = NameName;
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.ClockedIn = ClockedIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just writing the same thing.  `LoginManager`s privacy doesn't affect, or otherwise cascade down to, `User`s.  Since a `User` is being returned, and all of its properties are public, they're directly mutable.

Comment: I was considering making the `User` properties private, but the `User` class is more of a container of data making a `private set` without a constructor useless. In hindsight, `User` should probably be a `struct` or `record` and not a `class`. Thank you for the answer however, it has helped me to understand the context of my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to understand is that the lacking `set` accessor only prevents you from changing the value of the `CurrentUser` property itself. That is, it prevents you from changing it to another `User` object (or null). However, these rules only apply to the property itself, and not anything inside of it. The read-only nature of properties is not recursive.

If you want to prevent changing the properties inside the `User` object contained in `CurrentUser`, you'll need to have an immutable `User` object of some sort, or you must prevent direct access to the object and provide helper methods that allow retrieving certain data from the user without being able to change it. The two options are thus to hide direct access or to make the `User` object somehow immutable itself.

The first option is hiding access to the `User` object:

```
public User? CurrentUser { get; }

public string GetCurrentUserName() {
    return CurrentUser?.Name;
}

public string GetCurrentUserUsername() {
    return CurrentUser?.UserName;
}
```

The above follows the so-called Law of Demeter, but I don't see it used too often as it is not ergonomic and bloats up classes. Only go this route if many of the details of the current user aren't important to code using the `LoginManager` and if such code doesn't need to be able to pass around the `User` object.

The second option has some suboptions. You can create an `IReadOnlyUser` interface that only exposes read-only properties:

```
interface IReadOnlyUser {
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Username { get; }
}

public class User : IReadOnlyUser {
    // although these have setters, they cannot be access through variables of type IReadOnlyUser (see below)
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class LoginManager {
    // you can use a field here instead of a property since it is private
    private User currentUser;

    // returns an read-only view of the user, so write accessors are not available
    public IReadOnlyUser CurrentUser {
        get { return currentUser; }
    }
}

// usage
var lm = new LoginManager();
Console.WriteLine(lm.CurrentUser.Name);  // okay because IReadOnlyUser has a read accessor for Name
lm.CurrentUser.Name = "foo";   // not allowed because IImutableUser does not expose a write accessor
}
```

Additionally, you can do as in the other answer and make the fields in the `User` class read-only, either with `readonly` fields or with properties that only have `get` accessors. It depends on whether you feel there are cases where you should be able to modify properties of `User` objects, just not in the context of the `LoginManager`.

Finally, if you do not control the `User` class, you can create a facade class that wraps a `User` object but only exposes getters:

```
public class ReadOnlyUser {
    private User user;
    public ReadOnlyUser(User user) { this.user = user; }
    public string Name { get { return user.Name; } }
}

// in LoginManager
private ReadOnlyUser currentUser;
public ReadOnlyUser CurrentUser { 
    get { return currentUser; } 
    set {
        currentUser = new ImmutableUser(value);
    }
}

// usage
var lm = new LoginManager();
lm.CurrentUser = userFromSomewhereElse;
Console.Log(lm.CurrentUser.Name);  // okay because ReadOnlyUser exposes this property from the underlying User class
lm.CurrentUser.Name = "foo";  // not allowed because ReadOnlyUser doesn't have a setter for Name
```

There is, in my mind, no particular single right answer. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Having the interface named `IImmutableUser` is misleading. The interface does not represent an immutable object as the object can be mutated by the underlying implementation. `IUser` will do.

Comment: @VapidLinus Yes, I think that's reasonable. I probably picked the name because I was thinking that there could be a mutable version as well. But there probably wouldn't need to be an interface in that case. I will say, though, that I don't assume interfaces represent immutable constructs by default so I do feel like it might be worth putting it in the name. I don't think there's a definite right answer though. I'll think on it and then edit my post.

Comment: If anything, the interface would be called `IReadOnlyUser` which follows how `IReadOnlyList` is structured. It is not immutable, it is read only from the consumer's perspective. However, the way I usually do it is have an interface `IUser` and then a `MutableUser : IUser` and a `ImmutableUser : IUser` if I do ever need both.

Comment: @VapidLinus Perfect. I'll edit

Comment: Nice. Nitpick however. The `ReadOnlyUser` implementation (not the interface) in your last example IS actually immutable, so that one can happily be `ImmutableUser` 